# Cannot match any routes in Angular 2.1

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, rxjs, zone

I am using Angular 2.1.0 in a Visual Studio 2015 AspNetCore project and having an issue with routing in my lazy loaded modules. The error is as below:

> core.umd.js:3257 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'Home/MyList' Error: Cannot match any
>   routes. URL Segment: 'Home/MyList'
>       at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:31534/libraries/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:769:20)
>       at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (http://localhost:31534/libraries/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:747:33)
>       at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/operator/catch.js:52:31)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/Subscriber.js:128:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/Subscriber.js:102:18)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/Subscriber.js:128:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/Subscriber.js:102:18)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/Subscriber.js:128:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/Subscriber.js:102:18)
>       at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:31534/libraries/rxjs/Subscriber.js:128:26)

I have followed the [Tour Of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and adapted it according to the [lazy load topic here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load)
I am loading a login page first `{Home/Login}` in the Bootstrapped module called `AppModule`. On clicking login I want to show the next page `MyList`, `{Home/MyList}`  which is lazily loaded into a feature module called `MyModule`.

> `MyModule` is based on the `HeroModule` from the second link above.

`MyList` page and related component is the first page/component under `MyModule` which also has a `MyListDetail` page/component `{Home/MyListDetail}`.

I navigate to `{Home/MyList}` on a button click using this code

```
let link = ['Home/MyList'];
this.router.navigate(link);
```

Why are my routes not being found? Here is how I have them setup.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home/Login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'Home/MyList', loadChildren: 'scripts/My.Module#MyModule' }  

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**login-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule }        from '@angular/router';

import { LoginCmpnt }  from './Login';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: 'Home/Login', component: LoginCmpnt}
  ])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

**MyList-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterModule }        from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { MyListComponent }  from './MyListComp';
import { MyListDetailComponent }  from './MyListDetailComp';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    children:   [{ path: 'Home/MyList',    component: MyListComponent },
         { path: 'Home/MyListDetail/:id', component: MyListDetailComponent }]
  }];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild([routes]), SharedModule ],
    exports: [RouterModule]})

export class MyListRoutingModule {}
```

In the `MyList-routing.module` above what should I put for the path against `MyComponent`? The login method routes to `Home/MyList`

**EDIT**

Even this with the slash preceding the path in the login click doesn't work.

```
let link = ['/Home/MyList'];
this.router.navigate(link);
```

Comment: Have you tried `let link = ['/Home/MyList'];` (added `/`)?

Comment: Yes. That did not work either. My routes are not setup with the preceding forward slash. I tried adding the forward slash in the setup as well when I added it to the login button code

Comment: You must not set up the routes with a leading slash but if you are not navigating to a sibling or child route you must add the leading slash when navigating to a route.

Comment: I tried that combination too. Still no workie.

Comment: I don't say that's the the only possible cause, but it's not obvious from your question where you have the routerLink. Whether the leading slash is required or not depends on where the routerLink is. Therefore it's possible that you don't need it. I haven't used child routes from other modules and therefore don't know other possible causes.

Comment: The login module/component and the MyList Module/component are in the same folder

Comment: It's not about whether they are in the same folder, it's about if the new route can be reached by a relative path. For relative navigation `/` can be omitted.

Comment: I think they can be, because when I type it in the browser url bar it works, but the code navigating to that link doesn't

Comment: the only way I can check if a path can be reached from the calling module is seeing if they are in the same location or not or do I need to go up a folder or not. What other way is there?

Comment: Not sure what folders you talk about but route paths and the folders that contain the components (if this are the folders you're talking about) don't have to correlate and with routerLink only route paths are relevant.

Comment: The login button click code is in a module that loads the first time the url is called. My List page is to be called lazily after the login click and it is in the same path as far as I know. Does that need any alteration of the path then since its lazily loaded? I used the full url too and that too did not work. I have followed the example in the links I have provided in the question above. Not sure what is going wrong with route detection.

Comment: There are a few questions about routes in lazy loaded modules with good answers alredy. As mentioned I haven't used this myself yet and can't help here. I just had the suspicion that there is something unclear about absolute and relative paths and tried to iron that out ;-)

Comment: ah. ok no worries. any little bit helps :) I've been trying to find some answers around this problem with routes without much success

Answer (score -1):

Lazy loaded module most be like this:

```
 export class default MyModule{

 }
```

and in `app.routing` you most use load Child.